# Python 3-ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2)

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

Hi I am a new to computer visionand stackoverflow  and I have a problem with my python 3 program on Windows,as the cv2.findContours() function returns 2 instead of three values as in the documentation. I passed 2 values for return to solve the bug,the type of the first(image) is a list and that of the second (cnts)is an int32 but none of them is abled to be used in cv2.drawContours() without bugging here I use image as parameter in  because it is the only list returned so I guess it is the contours list cv2.drawContours().So here is the code:

```
#This is the program for a document scanner so as to extract a document
#from any image and apply perspective transform to show it as final result
import numpy as np
import cv2
import imutils
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
cap=cv2.VideoCapture(0)
ret,img=cap.read()
img1=img.copy()
cv2.imshow('Image',img1)
img1=cv2.cvtColor(img1,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
img1=cv2.bilateralFilter(img1,7,17,17)
img1=cv2.Canny(img1,30,200)
image,cnts=cv2.findContours(img1,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
#cnts=np.asarray(cnts,dtype='uint8')
cnts=np.array(cnts)

cv2.imshow('Edge',img1)
print('cnts var  data type',cnts.dtype)
#print("Hi")

img=cv2.drawContours(img,[image],-1,(255,255,0),3)
```

Here is the python idle shell result appearing now:

```
cnts var  data type is int32
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\PyCharm Projects\Test_1_docscanner.py", line 20, in <module>
    img=cv2.drawContours(img,[image],-1,(255,255,0),3)
TypeError: contours is not a numpy array, neither a scalar
```

Comment: Documentation specifys 2 values being returned, not 3...
https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#cv2.findContours

Comment: what type is image? from reading the docs i'd think its a list of vectors.

Comment: @seven_seas Thanks I am using cv2 version 4.2 and in a tutorial pdf that I download online the python version they are using requires cv2.findContours() to return 3 variables and not 2 as they used in their examples

Comment: @seven_seas  yes and image is a list and cnts is an int32 I am thinking to change my opencv version so as to solve this problem hopefully they won't be any further issues

Comment: what is in the list? scalars or numpy arrays? if yes try using those

Comment: idle shell says that it is neither a scalar nor a numpy array it says that it's data type=17 I am confused I don't what that is supposed to mean,here is the error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\PyCharm Projects\Test_1_docscanner.py", line 21, in <module>
    img=cv2.drawContours(img,[image],-1,(255,255,0),3)
TypeError: contours data type = 17 is not supported

Comment: I know but what about the things IN the list. not the list itself

Comment: @seven_seas here is a small piece of it's content  the content in it, it has 12607 lines in the idle python shell:[array([[[166, 380]],

       [[165, 381]],

       [[165, 382]],

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working finally,the following I did:

- First I had previously messed up with most of my environmental variables haven suppressed some system variables. So I with help of a friend I retrieved as much as I could and deleted those I had stupidly ignorantly created.
- Secondly I uninstalled all other python versions(at least I tried) though it seems that I still see their icons around(they seem to be "undeletable") and even the one I was using(Python3.7.3). I then install Python 3.7.4.
- Thirdly,and that must be the answer is that I added this line cnts=imutils.grab_contours(cnts) before the cv2.drawContours() functions. Getting this from imutils package from Adrian Rosebrock github. my code now works because of that line which helps to parse the contours for whatever cv2.drawContours() opencv version you are using thereby avoiding conflicts of versions originating from cv2.findContours() function used prior to cv2.drawContours().

  > In conclusion I tried imutils.grab_contours() previously to these changes on my python3.7.3 but it did not work. But I believe above all the combination of "cnts=imutils.grab_contours(cnts)" and the update to Python3.7.4,is what solved the issue.

Hope this is helpful